# Bundling HDMI cables and power cables: can it stand the RF?

Tags: rf, cables

I need to run a large number (12) of HDMI cables along with some AC power cables (two, for monitor power.)

I was hoping to be able to put them all together into a sleeve to make them more manageable.

I know for sure that doing that with analog VGA cables would cause tremendous amounts of signal loss. However, with HDMI being digital, I assume they will fare much better.

Is this practical, or do I need to give them some separation to prevent interference?

The cables will be about 10 ft long, and I'll probably bundle the low speed USB 2.0 cables in the same trunk.

Comment: Should be no issues.

Comment: Don't forget to consider those cables' temperature ratings--if the mains cabling carries any significant current, the hdmi bundled with it will also heat up too.

Comment: Can you try it in a temporary way, just in case something goes horribly wrong? It's a lot of cables - can you get a conduit/whatever you're running them through with a separator?